# $IJ =(I\cap J)(I+J)$ holds in a PID? $I,J$ Ideals of a PID

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, principal-ideal-domains

One inequality is obvious, but the other one im not sure if holds.
Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

Let's take $I=(a)$ and $J=(b)$. Then $IJ=(ab)$. $I\cap J= (\operatorname{lcm}(a,b))$ and $I+J=(\operatorname{gcd}(a,b))$. The fact that lcm and gcd exist is due to the fact that we're working in a UFD. Therefore $(I\cap J)(I+J)=(\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)\cdot\operatorname{gcd}(a,b))=(ab)$. This holds generally for principal ideals in a UFD, but since every ideal in a PID is principal, it holds for all ideals $I,J$.